# Can I activate YouTube's "watch later" function on my mobile phone only?

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to have YouTube’s “watch later” function be active only on my mobile phone rather than on all of my devices and web browsers?

I want to deactivate this feature when using my web browser, but keep it activated on my phone (or others devices unless in the web browser).

Comment: Your first paragraph says you want it *only* on your phone, not on your "devices". Your second paragraph says you *do* want it on your "devices", but not in your browser.

Comment: Either don't log into Google/YouTube on your web browser, or log in with a different account.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but it is possible to use more than one YouTube account. You could use a second account for your mobile phone so the watch later functionality is only keeping track for that account. Note that YouTube now also has the ability to have more than one channels.

I don't know for sure if this funcionality is enough or that you need a separate account.